# Eclipse Dark no windows

Tags: eclipse, ide

O Eclipse Luna foi lançado, e com veio um novo tema disponível "Dark", 
sempre gostei de temas mais escuros, por causa de uma fotossensibilidade.

No linux o tema Dark fica perfeito porque as barras de rolagens, as alça das views (aqueles 3 pontinhos quando você minimiza por exemplo o Outline ) também ficam na cor escura.

Por outro lado no Windows as barras de rolagens, as alça das views, e abas não ficam escuros.

**Pergunto: Há como deixar esses itens acima e qualquer outro não citado com cor escura?**

A ideia e ficar como o Visual Studio
Visual Studio Dark : [Imagem](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-92/3716.01_5F00_RTM.png)

Eclipse Luna Dark : [Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgS4g.png)

Como se trate de uma customização estética para uns e ergonômica para outros acredito que vale a pergunta.

Comment: Você pode mudar as cores das barras de rolagem do Windows no painel de controle, mas vai afetar todos os programas que usam a barra padrão. Infelizmente, se o Eclipse não permitir customização, não tem outro jeito.

Answer (score 2):

Ainda falta muito para os projetos opensource (Eclipse e Netbeans) terem um tema dark bacana no Windows como o VS. O tema dark do Eclipse Luna já é um passo.

Como o Renan mencionou, é possível usar um tema de auto contraste via painel de controle, porém todo seu sistema ficará "Dark". Não existe uma maneira ainda do [Eclipse estilizar alguns elementos](http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/#notes) como barras de rolagem, botões, entre outros.

No caso do Netbeans, esses elementos são customizáveis a partir do [Look'n Feels](http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-a-interface-nimbus-de-look-and-feel-para-suas-aplicacoes-swing/25163), porém o Netbeans não tem uma tema Dark padrão e os [temas customizados](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46003/dark-nimbus-theme) que temos atualmente são um pouco feios na minha opinião.

Outra alternativa para utilizar temas escuros com uma IDE Java é adotar o [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) que já tem um tema Dark bem feito para todas as plataformas (Windows, Mac e Linux). Porém com a versão Community só é possível programar com Java SE.

**Update**

O Eclipse Luna 4.4 já vem com um tema dark padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/20/dark-theme-top-eclipse-luna-feature-5/

Comment: E NetBeans nada?

Comment: @JorgeB. até hoje nada. Estou no aguardo pois uso ele também.